# Rendering a React Widget on third party site

Tags: reactjs, express, web, web-applications, widget

i'm looking  for some advice on how I should go about creating my next project. I would like to create an app that allows users to embed widgets on their own personal sites. An example would be, the user could create events on my app, and then copy code to embed on their site that would display the events.

My hope was that I would be able to give them a minfied/uglified script that would handle fetching their data from my app's api, and even possibly allowing  someone using the widget to post data to my app. Is that feasible?

What I am really unsure of :

1) How would I handle fetching data from my server? Are there CORS/other concerns I need to handle when fetching it?

2) I dont want users to have to go to a url to render my code, I just want to provide the minfied/uglified/compiled to es5 code to them. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: 1) You could load whole widget with data through JSONP method, that way you could avoid the CORS hassle. 2) Having the data as well in that minified code? Depending on how much data you would have, this could be huge snippet and I would advise against that, especially if the data can change.